# inserting image in the table

Tags: php, html

What is the problem in this code? I want to insert the images in the table, but it only shows crack or unidentified image.

**code:**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("shop");
    $res=mysql_query("select * from products");
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {        
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";?> '<img src=" <?phpecho data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '?> "height="100" width="100" />'<?php echo "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']); ?>` The `echo` and you put the singles quotes in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line

```
echo "<td>";?> '<img src=" <?phpecho data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '?> "height="100" width="100" />'<?php echo "</td>";
```

Here quote issue and spacing issue like `<?phpecho` and `"height="100"`

with this

```
echo "<td>";?> <img src=' <?php echo 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']); ?>' height="100" width="100" /><?php echo "</td>";
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some errors. Try this line:

```
echo '<td><img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . ' height="100" width="100" /></td>';
```

Btw. you should not use mysql_* as it is decreapted since PHP 5.5 and will be removed in the future. Use mysqli_* or PDO instead.